# Poner enlace en un div

Tags: css

Quiero poner enlaces en diferentes div, pero que al enlace sólo se le pueda hacer click dentro del div. No quiero que el enlace sea visible al pasar el ratón por los lados del div como en este ejemplo:

```css
<style>
    .caja {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .caja .panel {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .panel div {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="caja">
    <div class="panel">
        <a href="">
            <div>Opción 1</div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div>Opción 2</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al pasar el ratón por fuera del div Opción 1 o el div Opción 2 el enlace sigue visible y no quiero que sea así

Cómo lo puedo arreglar?

Gracias

Comment: ¿te refieres al subrallado y al color? Si es así entonces agrega esto a tu css: `.panel a {  text-decoration: none; color: black; }` y luego `.panel a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: blue; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo, elimina el div, no es necesario. Utiliza la etiqueta `<a>` dándole el mismo formato que le asignabas al `<div>`.

```css
        .caja {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 50%;
        }
    
        .caja .panel {
            border: 1px solid green;
            width: 40%;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    
        .panel div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 50%;
        }
    
        .holaMundo {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 50%;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="caja">
        <div class="panel">
            <a href="" class="holaMundo">
                Opción 1
            </a>
            <a href="" class="holaMundo">
                Opción 2
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que entendí solo quieres que el enlace se muestre si el mouse está posicionado sobre el div. Prueba con esto, lo hice solo con el primer enlace

```js
function test2() {
  ok1 = document.getElementById("ok1");
  ok1.style.display = "none";
}

function test() {
  ok1.style.display = "";
}
```

```css
    .caja {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .caja .panel {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .panel div {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .div1, .div2{width:auto; height:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="div1" onmouseover="test()" onmouseout="test2()">
            <a id="ok1" href="" >Opción 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <a id="ok2" href="" >Opción 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```